# jQuery .each loop pausing for iframe to fully load

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, load, each

I need to pause the .each loop giving the iframe time to load. Is there a way to do this? I've researched callbacks and so forth with no luck. I don't want a timeout because I need to make sure the iframe src loads completely.

```
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  traditional: true,
  url: '/Reportedit/exportPdfCharts',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: 'false',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(data) {

    $.each(data, function() {

        var url = "/Reportedit/createonechart";

        $("#iframe-chart").attr("src", url);

        //NEED TO PAUSE HERE UNTIL iframe source has completely loaded.


    });

  }
});
```

Comment: You can hook up an onload event on the iframe, but since ajax calls are asynchronous you cannot pause mid-call. If you need to wait, then AJAX may not be the right tool to use.

Comment: you can't pause a $.each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming, since your code seems to show this is the case, that you are updating the same iframes source, not a different one.  Either way, you can modify the code below, but it is for the same iframe.

You can just detect the load event being fired each time you update the source, and recursively call the same function in the load event function until you reach the end of the array

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
      loadFrame(data, 0);
    }
 });


function loadFrame(arr, i) {
   //tell it what to do when the frame loads, but just once, since we
   //are incrementing i
   $('#iframe-chart').once('load', function(){
     if (i<arr.length) { loadFrame(arr, i++); }
   });
   var url = "/Reportedit/createonechart"; 
   //you'll need some logic here to figure out which url to load
   $("#iframe-chart").attr("src", url);
 });
```

Comment: I could not vote on this till I had enough points on Stackoverflow LOL thanks Dave sorry for the delayed answer...